# I'm perplexed, why is my cloth rim tape not sticking?

Tags: rims, rim-tape

I have a pair of Velocity Deep V wheels (silver, from [Velo Mine](http://www.velomine.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=87_172_173&products_id=903&zenid=4mk0n47nle9mhaks75c3r1vbu7)) and have a roll of [BBB BTI-98 16 mm tape](http://bbbcycling.com/bike-parts/rim-tapes/BTI-98/). I tried to apply it today and the adhesive will *not* stick to the rim. It just kept sliding. Moreover, the part of the tape that I attempted to apply to the rim no longer is as sticky as it was initially. What gives?

Comment: I'd guess the rim had oil on it.  Either that or the tape is old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had rim tape before that didn't stick to the rim, but did stick to itself - which is all that matters really.  As long as the rim tape won't separate from it's ends, it's doing it's job, plus the valve will stop it sliding around.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll check out the tape again and ensure that it sticks to itself on either end.